# Content Type default image dependent on field value

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7

I have a content type of **resource** that has five different resource types (video, article, book, etc.). Each of these resources has a main image field (field_image). If the user doesn't provide an image I want to fallback to a default image. However, I would like the default image to be based on the type of resource (video, article, book, etc.). Is there a module or solution to do this within the Drupal UI? I need the image to be attached to the content type (not hard coded in templates) so that it displays properly on detail, list, and other view pages.

**Expected Functionality**

- Resource: field_type = article; field_image = default_article.jpg
- Resource: field_type = book; field_image = default_book.jpg
- Resource: field_type = video; field_image = default_video.jpg

**What I've tried**

*Google*: I've tried but failed to find anything that would make this possible. I understand by default Drupal allows only one default image per content type. I could make a new content type for each of my five types, but that seems unnecessary and clunky.

*Hard code*: I have a template for my resource detail page where I've hard coded the relevant default image to show if there is no image present, but this doesn't scale well as I have many views (resource list, related resources, etc.) where I am displaying resource images.

*Conditional Fields*: I've tried the module Field Dependencies (e.g., when field_type = x, set field_image = y), but it doesn't appear to work with files.

Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for every image field you can set default image when defining/editing content type. Why don't you use that?

Comment: The problem is that I have one content type (resource) that I need to have as many as 5 different default images depending on the type (field) that is set. I could create 5 different content types and set the default images, but the resource types are very similar and the type is really only used for categorization (video, article, etc.)

Comment: But you can set default image per every field, not per content type?!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following... each resource has one image field, so I can only set 1 default image... correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`hook_field_attach_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_view_alter/7) is your way to go, if your view uses the content display (and not field by field). If your view relies on field display, you can try `hook_field_attach_load()`.

```
function yourmodule_field_attach_view_alter(&$output, $context) {
  // Append RDF term mappings on displayed taxonomy links.
  if ($context['entity_type'] == 'node' && $context['entity']->type == 'resource') {
    foreach (element_children($output) as $field_name) {
        if ($field_name == 'field_resource') {
            $element = &$output[$field_name];
            foreach ($element ['#items'] as $delta => $item) {
                yourmodule_defaultimg($item, $node->field_resource_type['und'][0]['value']);
            }
        }
    }  
  }
}

function yourmodule_defaultimg(&$item, $resource_type) {

    switch($resource_type) {
      case "Article":
        $filename = 'default_resource_article.jpg';
        $uri = 'public://default_images/default_resource_article.jpg';
        break;
      case "Book":
        $filename = 'default_resource_book.jpg';
        $uri = 'public://default_images/default_resource_book.jpg';
        break;
      case "Video":
        $filename = 'default_resource_video.jpg';
        $uri = 'public://default_images/default_resource_video.jpg';
        break;
      case "Tool":
        $filename = 'default_resource_tool.jpg';
        $uri = 'public://default_images/default_resource_tool.jpg';
        break;
      case "Picture of Practice":
        $filename = 'default_resource_picture-of-practice.jpg';
        $uri = 'public://default_images/default_resource_picture-of-practice.jpg';
        break;
    }

    $item['uri'] = $uri;
    $item['filename'] = $filename;
}
```

Comment: This worked great! I had to make a few tweaks but overall it's much cleaner and it's working on all of my views - thanks! One thing I didn't mention was that I'm using the "rewrite results" option in views. It looks like this causes drupal to append an array at index[0] onto each $output[field_name] that is referenced in the rewrite results option. Altering this portion of the array allowed me to alter the results that are rendered in the view. As for the actual node page, I'm still calling the same function in the process_page() function.

Comment: Can you share how this might be set up differently for Profile2 fields? I have Men and Women users, but they both use the Main profile type. I'd like to have two default silhouette images in case the user does not upload their own photo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I managed to do to solve this. If anyone has a better suggestion I would love to hear it.

I have two places where I render resources: the node page and within a view.

I added the following functions to my template.php file for my theme.

**This function to preprocess the node page:**

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if($vars['node']->type == 'resource') {
        renderResourceDefaultImg($vars['node'], 'node');
    }
}
```

**and this function to prerender the view block:**

```
function MYTHEME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    if($view->current_display == 'BLOCKID') {
        foreach($view->result as $resource) {
            renderResourceDefaultImg($resource, 'view');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the renderResourceDefaultImg function that I added to the bottom of my template.

```
function renderResourceDefaultImg($resource, $displayType) {

    $resource_type_view = $resource->field_field_resource_type[0]['rendered']['#markup'];
    $resource_type_node = $resource->field_resource_type['und'][0]['value'];

    $resource_type = (!empty($resource_type_view)) ? $resource_type_view : $resource_type_node;

    switch($resource_type) {
      case "Article":
        $filename = 'default_resource_article.jpg';
        $uri = 'public://default_images/default_resource_article.jpg';
        break;
      case "Book":
        $filename = 'default_resource_book.jpg';
        $uri = 'public://default_images/default_resource_book.jpg';
        break;
      case "Video":
        $filename = 'default_resource_video.jpg';
        $uri = 'public://default_images/default_resource_video.jpg';
        break;
      case "Tool":
        $filename = 'default_resource_tool.jpg';
        $uri = 'public://default_images/default_resource_tool.jpg';
        break;
      case "Picture of Practice":
        $filename = 'default_resource_picture-of-practice.jpg';
        $uri = 'public://default_images/default_resource_picture-of-practice.jpg';
        break;
    }

    if($displayType == 'view') {
      $resource->field_field_image[0]['rendered']['#item']['filename'] = $filename;
      $resource->field_field_image[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri'] = $uri;
    } elseif($displayType == 'node') {
      $resource->field_image['und'][0]['uri'] = $uri;
      $resource->field_image['und'][0]['filename'] = $filename;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could derive your default image from your field type with a rewrite in a view:
if you have a field `field_type = article/video/...` specified in a taxonomy. you could get the default image by specifying it as:
  `default_[field_type].jpg`
(where `field_type` is a token). You'd want to do this if there were 'No results' for your image name.
The solutions above would be much more generally applicable.